# How to install an executable with dune?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I am building my OCaml project with the following `dune` file.

```
(executable
 (name myapp)
 (libraries unix))
```

How to modify it so that when I run `dune build` (or many `dune install`) the executable is copied (without the `.exe` extension) into the folder of my choice (e.g., `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: I would review the [User Actions](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/actions.html) section of the Dune documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dune file can be given an `(install)` stanza to install your executable with your chosen name in a directory of your choice, such as ~/bin or ~/.local/bin: see https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#install.

However, you will normally need to be root in order to install your executable in /usr/local/bin.  If, like me, you have dune installed in an opam switch with user ownership then dune cannot do that for you in a way which I find satisfactory.  There may be better ways to do it but in these circumstances I include a Makefile which has a build target which calls up `dune build --profile release` as user, and a PHONY install target which is intended to be called up as root and installs the executable in /usr/local/bin with the correct permissions, and which can give the binary any name it wants.